# Can a shiny page not restart when the page is reloaded/refresed?

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I created a web apps with R and shiny dashboard that has a login form.
When the user refresh/reload the page, shiny will restart and the user must re-enter the user and password.

Is it possible a shiny page not restart and the user don't need to login again when the page is reloaded/refresed?

Thankyou

Comment: Sure that's possible - it all depends on your server code. I guess you'll need to provide an example to get help.

Comment: You either control this in cookies yourself or maybe you can use `shinymanager` https://datastorm-open.github.io/shinymanager/

Comment: When the browser is refreshed the app is reloaded, that's standard web, I'm not sure what dark magic other commenters suggest you use.

When the user reloads the page a new `GET` request is made, no avoiding that. What you can do is store the session server-side and restore it after the reload: https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/bookmarking-state.html